# How can I make this go to a previous image instead of the next one?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

This is inside the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/hand-eye.jpg"

    var image2=new Image()
    image2.src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/floating.JPG"

    var image3=new Image()
    image3.src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/lovers%20ng.jpg"
</script>
```

This is in the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step=1

    function slideit(){
        if (!document.images)
            return
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

        if (step<3)
            step++
        else
            step=1
        }
        slideit()
</script>
```

So I found this code for creating a slideshow, where I just click to step up an image. I'm calling it from a button. But I can't figure out how to alter this code so I can step back instead of forward when a different button is pressed that is a previous button. I'd appreciate any help, I'm not the best at javascript at all.
Thanks in advance.

This is where I'm at: http://slidetester.tumblr.com/

Comment: If you need "any " help, than i woudl consider using a javascript plugin for galleries, which might be simplier to install and use and maintain. Just type "javascript gallery" on google and tons of links will come up..

Comment: Yeah I used 'the viewer-mootools' instead, work out much easier and better, you can see it on my test page under artworks/illustrations http://testerwebby.tumblr.com/

Comment: can you consider upvoting my comment if it was useful to you, please?

Comment: Hey, wonderful animation? is it your job? I could be intrerested in... how to contact you?

Comment: I can't up vote a comment, only an answer and I still can't do that because I've only got 6 rep. Thanks, em no not yet I guess, but you could could totally shoot me an email if you like what you see in my reel. dillon.brannick@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make it so rather than incrementing the picture via `step++` the picture number is decremented. Look up how to do this. Also you will need to change the condition for when it runs out of pictures to go back to. I don't want to give you the full code as this should be a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know how to make a button and assign a separate function to it, so instead of slideit() we can call another function which we can call slideitbackwards()

```
function slideitbackwards() {
  if (!document.images)
    return
  document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
  if (step > 1) //Change this line to the minimum image number
    step-- //subtract instead of add
  else
    step = 3 //Set this to maximum value instead of minimum
  }
```

Comment: No problem calling the function, but now the image, when I use the slideitbackwards it goes from image1 to image 2 to image 1 to image 3, instead of going straight to image 3. But I don't get it because you're saying that if its >image 1 go up an image and if it =image1(only other possibility go to image 3, but its not doing that.

Comment: Fixed it a little, Now each function, when first called goes to image1, even when already on image1 and then if the same function is called again it will run as normal.

Comment: Glad to see you got it to work to some extent. I believe what you have with it starting at image1 is in your implementation. The other function has a declaration of step=1. I assumed that this function would share that same variable, did you make a separate variable for this function?

Comment: this is what its written like at the moment                   <script type="text/javascript">

var step=1
function slideit(){
    if (!document.images)
     return
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    if (step<3)
     step++
    else
     step=1
}

function slideitback() {
    if (!document.images)
     return
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    if (step>1)
     step--
    else
     step=3 
}
</script>

Comment: so no I didn't, but I did try putting it in twice too and it made no difference.

Comment: it like to go in the wrong the direction once and then continue as it should

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function and have it triggered by a button:
    function slideitBack(){
    if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    if (step>1)
    step--
    else
    step=3
    }